# output.value to file not adding new line break when using \n or \r\n

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried using both \n and \r\n however, the exported file does not contain the line break. Any idea what I am missing?

I would like the text to return as:

```
indexname_text
indextype_text
```

Below is my code

```
<!-- Button to download -->
<button type="button" class="button" id="dwn-btn" style="vertical-align:middle">Download as .bat file</button>

document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
var copyIndexNameField = document.getElementById("indexName");
var copyIndexName = document.getElementById("indexName");
var copyIndexTypeField = document.getElementById("IndexTypeCheckBox");
var copyIndexType = document.getElementById("IndexTypeTextBox");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
if (copyIndexNameField.value) {
    indexname_text += "--index-name " + copyIndexName.value + " ";
}
if (copyIndexTypeField.checked) {
    indextype_text += "--index-type " + copyIndexType.value;
}
output.value = 
    + indexname_text
    + "\n"
    + indextype_text;
var text = document.getElementById("output").value;
var filename = "export.bat";
download(filename, text);

function download(filename, text) {
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: This looks like javascript, not java.  In an HTML document, use `<br/>` for a line break.

Comment: Please show the definition of `download` function.

Comment: @geocodezip yes, javascript sorry. <br/> does not work.

Comment: @Kaiido, The button downloads a file named (export.bat) with the input values.

Comment: Looks like you are putting that text in an `<input>` element.  Not sure `<br>` or `\n` or `\r` will work there.  You might need to make it a  `<textarea>`.

Comment: I asked you to show us the definition of that function. We need to see the code.

Comment: @Kaiido sorry for the delay as I was was working on another project. I have updated my code with the code for the button. Apologize as I am new to this.

Comment: For the third time, We need to see the definition of the `dowload` function. The part in your code where there is `function download(arg1,arg2){ ...}`.

Comment: The function downloads a batch file @Kaiido

Comment: @Kaiido "the exported file does not contain the line break."...

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I assume they mean when read as text not when executed. But you could be right actually, this question doesn't miss unclarity.

Comment: @Kaiido Daniel_Knights is correct. The function downloads a batch file. I have added that function download. I hope that is what you are looking for.